# React-router v6: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'pathname')

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm using *react-router v6* and I'm trying to use a custom history to be able to navigate in redux actions (outside of a component). So I'm using `Router from 'react-router` instead of `BrowserRouter from 'react-router-dom` as mentionned in the doc.

Here is my code:

**index.js**

```
import myHistory from './utils/history';

import { Router } from 'react-router';

ReactDOM.render(
   <Provider store={store}>
      <Router history={myHistory}>
         <App />
      </Router>
   </Provider>,
   document.getElementById('root')
);
```

**App.js**

```
import React from 'react';

import MainNavigation from './components/navigations/MainNavigation';
import Routes from './routes/Routes';

const App = () => {
   return (
      <>
         <MainNavigation />
         <Routes />
      </>
   );
};

export default App;
```

**MainNavigation.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

const MainNavigation = () => {
   return (
      <>
         <nav className='navigation'>
            <ul>
               <li>
                  <Link to='/'>Home</Link>
               </li>
               <li>
                  <Link to='/contact'>Contact</Link>
               </li>

               <li>
                  <Link to='/about'>A propos</Link>
               </li>

               <li>
                  <Link to='/user-profile'>Votre compte</Link>
               </li>
            </ul>
         </nav>
      </>
   );
};

export default MainNavigation;
```

**Routes.js**

```
//** Import routers */
import {Route, Routes as Routing } from 'react-router-dom';

const Routes = () => {
   return (
      <Routing>
         <Route path='/' element={<Home />} />
         <Route path='/about' element={<About />} />
         <Route path='/contact' element={<ContactForm />} />
         <Route path='/user-profile' element={<UserAccount />} />
      </Routing>
   );
};

export default Routes;
```

I really can't figure out why I got the error message **Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'pathname')**. It's working when I swap to BrowserRouter instead of Router but then I can't use history (*'navigate' now in v6*) in my app.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Your Router needs a location too (e.g. `<Router location={myHistory.location} history={myHistory}>`).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Hello @Emanuel, thank you for your answer. When I add a location to my router I have this error ```Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'createHref')```

Answer (score 0):

[You need to use `unstable_HistoryRouter` now](https://github.com/remix-run/react-router/issues/8264#issuecomment-991271554)

```js
import { createBrowserHistory } from 'history';
import { unstable_HistoryRouter as HistoryRouter } from 'react-router-dom';

let history = createBrowserHistory();

function App() {
  return (
    <HistoryRouter history={history}>
      // The rest of your app
    </HistoryRouter>
  );
}

history.push("/foo");
```