# React Router's v6 history.push('/') giving error of "undefined (reading 'pathname')" - url changes, but page stays the same

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, react-router, react-router-dom

I'm trying to change the page in a Redux Thunk action creator to take the user back "home" after they submit a form

The url changes when the action creator is invoked, but the page doesn't change

I can't use `BrowserRouter` beacuse I'm creating my own instance of `history`, but whenever I use `Router` I get the error

> TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'pathname')

I tried referencing [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69882407/react-router-v6-cannot-read-properties-of-undefined-reading-pathname) which is exactly the same problem I'm having, but it too is unresolved. The only answer given just throws the same error but replaces `pathname` with `createHref`

Needless to say I'm extremely grateful to anyone who can get me unstuck

Here's the code:

*history.js*

```js
import { createBrowserHistory } from 'history';
export default createBrowserHistory();
```

*App.js*

```js
import React from 'react'
import { Router, Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom'
import history from '../history'

import StreamCreate from './streams/StreamCreate'
import StreamDelete from './streams/StreamDelete'
import StreamEdit from './streams/StreamEdit'
import StreamList from './streams/StreamList'
import StreamShow from './streams/StreamShow'

import Header from './Header';

const App = () => {
    return (
        <div className="ui container">
            <Router history={history}>
                <Header />
                <Routes>
                    <Route path="/" exact element={ <StreamList /> } />
                    <Route path="/streams/new" exact element={ <StreamCreate /> } />
                    <Route path="/streams/edit" exact element={ <StreamEdit /> } />
                    <Route path="/streams/delete" exact element={ <StreamDelete /> } />
                    <Route path="/streams/show" exact element={ <StreamShow /> } />
                </Routes>
            </Router>
        </div>
    )
}

export default App
```

*actions*

```js
import history from '../history';

export const createStream = (formValues) => async (dispatch, getState) => {
    const { userId } = getState().authReducer // userId from auth
    const { data } = await streams.post('/streams', { ...formValues, userId })

    dispatch({ type: CREATE_STREAM, payload: data })
    history.push("/")
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can separate this history responsibility from push to component that dispatch this action. And after dispatch from your component, you can use the hook `useNavigate()` to navigate to `/`.

History is not working in react-router v6.

Answer (score 1):

If you happend to migrate to react router 6 then you might need to check their [migration guide](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/upgrading/v5)

React Router v6 introduces a new navigation API that is synonymous with  and provides better compatibility with suspense-enabled apps.

You can use `useNavigate()` hook and then have access to navigate

```
 let navigate = useNavigate();
```

Answer (score 1):

react router v6 doesn't support `exact` and `history` anymore.

```
// old - v5 <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />

// new - v6 <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />

const navigate = useNavigate();
```

Answer (score 1):

[Turns out it is still possible to maintain a global history instance so that abstracting programmatic navigation to your action creators is still possible](https://github.com/remix-run/react-router/issues/8264#issuecomment-991271554)

Happy to see you, `unstable_HistoryRouter`(:

```js
import { createBrowserHistory } from 'history';
import { unstable_HistoryRouter as HistoryRouter } from 'react-router-dom';

let history = createBrowserHistory();

function App() {
  return (
    <HistoryRouter history={history}>
      // The rest of your app
    </HistoryRouter>
  );
}

history.push("/foo");
```

Answer (score 0):

The error you see is because you haven't passed the correct props to the low-level `Router` component. There is no `history` prop for the `react-router-dom@6` `Router` component.

[Router](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/api#router)

> ```
> declare function Router(
>   props: RouterProps
> ): React.ReactElement | null;
>
> interface RouterProps {
>   basename?: string;
>   children?: React.ReactNode;
>   location: Partial<Location> | string;
>   navigationType?: NavigationType;
>   navigator: Navigator;
>   static?: boolean;
> }
> ```

Take a cue from the way the high-level routers instantiate the history object and internalize it.

Examine the [BrowserRouter](https://github.com/remix-run/react-router/blob/main/packages/react-router-dom/index.tsx#L133-L160) implementation for example:

> ```
> export function BrowserRouter({
>   basename,
>   children,
>   window
> }: BrowserRouterProps) {
>   let historyRef = React.useRef<BrowserHistory>();
>   if (historyRef.current == null) {
>     historyRef.current = createBrowserHistory({ window });
>   }
>
>   let history = historyRef.current;
>   let [state, setState] = React.useState({
>     action: history.action,
>     location: history.location
>   });
>
>   React.useLayoutEffect(() => history.listen(setState), [history]);
>
>   return (
>     <Router
>       basename={basename}
>       children={children}
>       location={state.location}
>       navigationType={state.action}
>       navigator={history}
>     />
>   );
> }
> ```

Create a `CustomRouter` that consumes a custom `history` object and manages the state:

```
const CustomRouter = ({ history, ...props }) => {
  const [state, setState] = useState({
    action: history.action,
    location: history.location
  });

  useLayoutEffect(() => history.listen(setState), [history]);

  return (
    <Router
      {...props}
      location={state.location}
      navigationType={state.action}
      navigator={history}
    />
  );
};
```

This effectively proxies the custom `history` object into the `Router` and manages the navigation state.

```
import React from 'react';
import { Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import Router from '../CustomRouter';
import history from '../history';

import StreamCreate from './streams/StreamCreate'
import StreamDelete from './streams/StreamDelete'
import StreamEdit from './streams/StreamEdit'
import StreamList from './streams/StreamList'
import StreamShow from './streams/StreamShow'

import Header from './Header';

const App = () => {
  return (
    <div className="ui container">
      <Router history={history}>
        <Header />
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/" element={<StreamList />} />
          <Route path="/streams/new" element={<StreamCreate />} />
          <Route path="/streams/edit" element={<StreamEdit />} />
          <Route path="/streams/delete" element={<StreamDelete />} />
          <Route path="/streams/show" element={<StreamShow />} />
        </Routes>
      </Router>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

You should also ensure you've `history@5` installed for compatibility with `react-router-dom@6`.